# TypeORM with multiple joins

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to use TypeORM for joining multiple tables, but the join doesn's seem to work as I expected.

```
await Item.find({
    relations: {
        seller: {
            userLocations: {
                location: true
            }
        }
    },
    select: {
        id: true,
        title: true,
        price: true,
        seller: {
            userLocations: {
                location: {
                    name: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I'm trying to get id, price, title from Item, and name from Location, but code I wrote doesn't give me location name. It works when I select additional field from seller and userLocations, but I don't want to expose any unnecessary data.

These are my Entity codes.

```
// Item.ts
@Entity("item")
class Item extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ unsigned: true })
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.items, { nullable: false })
    @JoinColumn({ name: "seller_id" })
    seller: User;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 30 })
    title: string;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 200, default: "" })
    description: string;

    @Column({ default: 0 })
    price: number;  
}

// User.ts
@Entity("user")
class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ unsigned: true })
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 16, unique: true })
    username: string;

    @OneToMany(() => UserLocation, userLocation => userLocation.user)
    userLocations: UserLocation[];

    @OneToMany(() => Item, item => item.seller)
    items: Item[];
}

// UserLocation.ts
@Entity("user_location")
class UserLocation extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ unsigned: true })
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.userLocations, { nullable: false })
    @JoinColumn({ name: "user_id" })
    user: User;

    @ManyToOne(() => Location, location => location.userLocations, { nullable: false })
    @JoinColumn({ name: "location_id" })
    location: Location;
}

// Location.ts
@Entity("location")
class Location extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ unsigned: true })
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 16, unique: true })
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(() => UserLocation, userLocation => userLocation.location)
    userLocations: UserLocation[];
}
```

Comment: What's the typeorm version you're on?

Comment: @RahulSharma Sorry for being late! It was 0.3.10.